# How to do something when my Javafx close?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to call one function when my JavaFX program close. I have few classes which extends Stage. So i don't know in which stage my program will close.

So the first way to do this is to override close function in every stage i got and to call my function from there.

But i guess that there should be also other way. Is there any final function that is always called just before our program close ? So i can implement that function to put what i need to be done before program closes in there ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Override [`stop()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Application.html#stop--) in your `Application` subclass:

```
public class MyApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        // startup code...
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        // executed when the application shuts down
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed ! Thank you so much.